# Get all photos with maximum size in an album

Tags: php, facebook, rest, api, facebook-graph-api

in Facebook API, I am just wondering if there is a way to return max sized images only in an album using images field. For example, when I use:

```
/ALBUM_ID?fields=images
```

It will return something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 1536, 
          "width": 2048, 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s2048x2048/65169_XXXXXX_n.jpg"
        }, 
        {
          "height": 720, 
          "width": 960, 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/65169_44590146XXXXXXXXn.jpg"
        }, 
        {
          "height": 540, 
          "width": 720, 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/65169_44XXXXXXX0984540_n.jpg"
        },
        { 
          ...
        },
        {
          "height": 97, 
          "width": 130, 
          "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s75x225/65169_44XXXXX_s.jpg"
        }
      ], 
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there such a way to request for max size image only? In this case, only the first entry in images array will be returned because that is the largest. Can I do that? Thank you in advance